# Can searching directory or file paths in Postgres benefit from a GIN index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

So we have a DB we are using to store metadata of files that we need to guarantee and audit.

given a typical file path of:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt
```

With typical usage in queries:

```sql
WHERE path LIKE '/dir1/dir2/dir3/%';
-- and 
WHERE path = '/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt';
```

Is there a way to configure and use a GIN index to speed up these searches?

For these queries assume there is no additional columns that can be used at this point in time.
Currently, we have a BTREE index of about 45GB (with VERY high cardinality since the field is mostly unique but not always), and it performs ok, but the data is growing at an increasing rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You need to make sure that your collation is "C" or your btree index is defined with the [text_patterns_ops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html), so that the LIKE operator can use it.  But if the LIKE operator is already using the btree index, there is nothing left to gain.